# BlazeDS default messaging for 1500 clients

Tags: apache-flex, spring, weblogic, messaging, blazeds

I am having Flex + Spring BlazeDS Integration + Java combination for my project. This project is deployed on weblogic server. As we know whenever a client connects to blazeDS it blocks one thread on the server and it is a limitation for the maximum number of concurrent clients for one BlazeDS instance.

In my case I am supposed to have around 300,000 updates every hour and at any moment of time around 500 concurrent client can be there. In extreme case it can be all 1500 clients connected to the application. What is the best possible solution for that?

If I try to convince my clients to use LCDS they would like to know the exact number that our current setup can support. For that I tried to use neoload but could not make much progress in that direction.

So If any body has used such a setup and can advise me what shall I do, it would be really great!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you having a problem?  Or do you just want clarification that your app will work without problems?

Comment: What do you mean by "blazeDS blocks one thread" ?

Comment: I have tested my application with 10 users and it is working fine. When we use Streaming channel then blazeDS uses one thread per client. I want to know if there will be around 1500 clients how will it work? I think it wont be able to support 1500 clients. So I need to know the solution for it.

Comment: Can anybody help me out with this? How can I support 1500 client (Streaming) using blazeDS on Weblogic? If it is not possible shall I go with LCDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research (we may have a similar situation, it seems that blazeDS is not able to use NIOs. [Here](http://blog.hiraash.org/2012/04/13/scaling-blazeds-with-servlet-3-concurrency/) is a link about it. They offer a solution that seems [broken](http://code.google.com/p/blazeds-servlet3-support/wiki/HowToUse) with newer versions of tomcat. So I guess blazeDS is not the one to use in your usecase.

If you cannot go with LCDS, a good free solution is [graniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229378), supporting asynchronous servlets